# Passing an integer wildcard to a SQL select query

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms

I've got a search function in an app I'm building, of which the operator can search by date, tracking number (waybill) or name of sender (or a combination of the 3).

Searching by any combination works... until the Waybill text box is empty. If it's empty I get this error:

> System.FormatException: 'Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int64.'

It is probably quite obvious, but the waybill field is an integer (bigint).

I've tried to set this up so that if the waybill field is empty, it includes all applicable waybill numbers based on the other search parameters. The code is below, and it seems obvious the reason is '%' doesn't form part of an integer. I've tried messing with it to no success and wondering if I should be using some form of regex to tie it together?

```
SELECT 
    LabID, GivenName, Surname, DOB, Sex, Service, Specimen, 
    ReferDate, WaybillNo, SendDate
FROM 
    US_Biotek
WHERE
    SenderName LIKE @SenderName 
    AND WaybillNo LIKE @WaybillNo 
    AND SendDate BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate

    ", conn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateFrom.Value
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTo.Value

    If cbName.SelectedText.Length > 5 Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SenderName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = cbName.SelectedItem
    Else
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SenderName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%"
    End If

    If txtWBno.Text.Length = 12 Then
        Dim a As Int64 = Convert.ToInt64(txtWBno.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@WaybillNo", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = a
    ElseIf txtWBno.Text.Length < 12 Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@WaybillNo", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = "%"
    End If

    conn.Open()
```

The end goal is to have it select all waybills if the text box is empty, to throw an error if the length of text is between 1 and 11 (should be 12) (got this part sorted), or to find that particular waybill if a correct number is entered.

Comment: Side note: you should **always** define a string length! Here for instance: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@SenderName", SqlDbType.VarChar)` - when using `SqlDbType.VarChar`, pass the valid max length of that parameter as the next param: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@SenderName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100)` ....

Comment: You can't do partial matches on numbers. If you want to do a partial match then you need to do a text comparison, so pass your parameter as text and convert the column value to text in the SQL code.

Comment: Change the `where` condition to cast the `WaybillNo` to a varchar, i.e. `cast(WaybillNo as varchar(20)) LIKE @WaybillNo `

Answer (score 1):

Following the comments I received, I ended up changing the column in SQL to a text field, and finding a way to only allow numeric characters in my text boxes.

```
    Private Sub txtWBNo_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtWBno.KeyPress

        If Not Char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub txtWBNo_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtWBno.TextChanged
        Dim digitsOnly As Regex = New Regex("[^\d]")
        txtWBno.Text = digitsOnly.Replace(txtWBno.Text, "")
    End Sub
```

The text boxes have a length limit set and I've defined the string length in the parameters as well.

```
                If cbName.SelectedText.Length > 5 Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SenderName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 90).Value = cbName.SelectedItem
                Else
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@SenderName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 90).Value = "%"
                End If


                If txtWBno.Text.Length = 12 Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WaybillNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = txtWBno.Text
                ElseIf txtWBno.Text.Length < 12 Then
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@WaybillNo", SqlDbType.VarChar, 12).Value = "%"
                End If
```

Thanks to all for the nudge in the right direction.